# copying XML file from URL returns incomplete file

Tags: java, xml, url, timeout

I am writing a small program to retrieve a large number of XML files. The program sort of works, but no matter which solution from stackoverflow I use, every XML file I save locally misses the end of the file. By "the end of the file" I mean approximately 5-10 lines of xml code. The files are of different length (~500-2500 lines) and the total length doesn't seem to have an effect on the size of the missing bit. Currently the code looks like this:

```
package plos;
import static org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile;
import java.io.File;

    public class PlosXMLfetcher {
        public PlosXMLfetcher(URL u,File f) {
            try {
                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(u, f);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PlosXMLfetcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
     }
}
```

I have tried using `BufferedInputStream` and `ReadableByteChannel` as well. I have tried running it in threads, I have tried using `read` and `readLine`. Every solution gives me an incomplete XML file as return.

In some of my tests (I can't remember which, sorry), I got a socket connection reset error - but the above code executes without error messages.

I have manually downloaded some of the XML files as well, to check if they are actually complete on the remote server - which they are.

Comment: Try copyURLToFile(URL source, File destination, int connectionTimeout,                 int readTimeout), maybe the connection is timing out.

Comment: I just tried this, with timeouts of 10000 and the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that somewhere along the way a BufferedWriter or BufferedOutputStream has not had `flush()` called on it.

Why not write your own copy function to rule out `FileUtils.copyURLToFile(u, f)`

```
public void copyURLToFile(u, f) {
    InputStream in = u.openStream();        
    try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
       try {                  
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int count;
          while ((count = in.read(buffer) > 0) {
             out.write(buffer, 0, count);
          }
          out.flush();
       } finally {
          out.close();
       }
    } finally {
       in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that too, at least with some of my other tests, but using copyURLtoFile() shouldn't have that issue. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Maybe the process which generates the XML files didn't ```flush()```?

Comment: The XML files are static documents online, I believe. If I enter the URL for a document in my browser, I get the entire file.

Comment: I just tested a different path to basically the same XML file, however using a different URL. This time it works, which leads me to think you might be correct about your assumption. But is there something I can do about this, when I don't have control of the XML files being served? While I could use the secondary URL, I would prefer to use the primary one (the one which doesn't appear to be flushed).

Comment: If you hit the URL in your browser and see the full XML page, it's an issue with the consumer. If you hit the URL in your browser and see a partial file, it's an issue with the producer. Simples!